# Intuition for saying $I - A$ is close to identity given only $||A||<1$, and not just $\|A\|$ small

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ denote a linear map with norm $\|A\| := \sup\{ \|Ax\|: \|x\| \leq 1\}$.

> **Theorem.** Linear maps *close to* the identity map have inverses, more precisely if $\|A\| < 1$, then the linear map $I-A$ is invertible.

The proof follows nicely from $\|A\|^p \to 0$ as $p \to \infty$ making $B_p := I + A + \dots + A^{p-1}$ a Cauchy sequence (which converge to linear maps) and analogues to geometric series $\displaystyle \lim_{p\to \infty} B_p (I - A) = I$. So in that sense, it is clear why $\|A\| < 1$ makes it all work.

However, I fail to see intuitively why we can say that $I-A$ is close to the identity map $I$, given $\|A\| < 1$ and not just sufficiently small $\|A\|$, I'm surely missing something obvious. Is (the convergence of) the geometric series the only way to see this?

Comment: Look at the eigenvalues.  $A$ and $I-A$ have the same eigenvectors, and for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, you have an eigenvalue $1-\lambda$ of $I-A$.

Comment: $\|A\|$ small $\implies$ $I - A$ is near $I$.

Comment: For you, $0.01 I = I - 0.99 I$ is near $I$?

Comment: @Paul 's answer is the essence of it. I would like to repeat it with a slight modification; $\|A\| <1$ implies the eigenvalues have modulus smaller than $1$. $I-A$ shifts the eigenvalues to the left of $1$, so The eigenvalues are separated from $0$.

Comment: @Ranc Thank you for the clarification, but what's been troubling me is that it isn't for $\|A\|$ sufficiently small, which would definitely makes sense, rather even if $\|A\| = 0.99$ it still works, which I could't wrap my head around except by analogy to the geometric series.

Comment: @Weaam This is precisely that. Take $\|A\|=0.99$, so the points in the *spectrum* have modul smaller than $0.99$. Points in the spectrum of $I-A$ are then separated from $0$ by at least $0.01$, so $0$ cannot be in the spectrum (hence the operator is invertible).

Comment: @Ranc  Ah, I get it now. Thanks for your patience. It is indeed intuitive and precise enough to show why $\|A\| < 1$ is close but not any larger. Can you please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: The second figure actually shows the spectrum of $I+A$.**

Neumann series, Behind the Scenes (read; Behind the Proof);

Suppose you have some operator $A$ such that $\|A\|<1$. It's spectrum is contained in the ball of radius $1$. It is actually a coroallry of the Neumann series theorem which we are discussing, but let's take that as a fact, for we try to realize what is happening *behind the proof*. When I picture the spectrum I would think about something like this:
[image]
The spectrum of $A$ is that odd shape, it is contained in a circle of radius $r<1$ about the origin (this is another not-so-easy fact, there are several theorems that show that, for instance Neumann series again. The formula for the spectral radius shows it too). Note I drew the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ as continuous shape, and that it contains $0$ (so $A$ is not invertible), but this has nothing to do with the rest of the intuitive geometric feeling i'm trying to communicate. You make take it to be discrete or whatever, but it must be in that ball of radius $r<1$.

Now look at $I-A$, the spectrum then looks like [image]

so it is separated from $0$.

Answer (score 4):

It is close to $I$ for the metric induced by the norm: the open ball of radius $r$, centred at identity, is:
$$B(I,r)=\bigl\{A\in\mathcal L(\mathbf R^n)\mid \lVert I-A\rVert < r\bigr\}$$
so what you've been proved is that the linear maps in $B(I,1)$ are invertible.

*Another argument*:

More generally, a matrix which is close enough to an invertible matrix is invertible too. This comes from the function $A\longmapsto\operatorname{rank} A$ being *locally constant* since the determinant is a continuous function.

A consequence of this is of course that $\operatorname{GL}(n,K)\;$ ($K=\mathbf R$ or $\mathbf C$) is an open subset of $\mathrm M(n,K)$.

Comment: +1 But honestly I can't see from this answer how that particular choice of $r$ is close enough but not any larger *intuitively*, except by returning to the convergence of the geometric series in the proof. Thank you.

Comment: A distance less than 1 makes $A$ invertible, but it results from the geometric series. Invertibility of matrices isn't so simple as invertibility of numbers. I'll add another argument, maybe more intuitive (which doesn't mean simpler to prove).

Comment: After all, even for a  real or complex number, you have to give arguments to prove that, starting from a non-zero number and adding a small enough amount, you still obtain a non-zero number.

Comment: I never suggested that invertibility is so simply, what I'm asking for (and surely appreciate your attempt to answer) is an intuitive explanation for why $\|A\|<1$ and not merely $\|A\|$ small justify us to call it $I-A$ close to $I$, and you provided superb answers for the latter, not the former. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow youd: you seem not to agree saying $I-A$ is close to $I$ because $\lVert A\rVert<1$, but would agree if it were $\lVert A\rVert<10^{-6}$, say?

Comment: Take $X = 0.5I$. Is $X-A$ close to $X$ given that $\|A\| < 1$? Of course not, for $A = X$ given a non-invertible $X-A = 0$, so $r = 1$ gives maps that are not close to the center! The particular choice of $r = 1$ requires an explanation, whether through the geometric series proof, or by comparing the spectrum of $A$ and $I-A$ and bounding the eigenvalues $\max \lambda$ to make sure $1-\lambda$ doesn't cross zero as was suggested in the comments. That choice of $r$ that we can still call them "close" is what my question is about. Thank you.

Comment: But anyway, ‘close to’ alone has no mathematical meaning.  If you don't specify a degree of vicinity, it is mathematically undefined. As I view it, it is only used in the context as a metaphor.